# Saving an image with PyQgis while adding a scalebar on it

Tags: pyqgis, scale-bar

I'm basically making a script to save an image in .png from Qgis with a script and I would like to add a scale bar on it.
I'm using this code :

```
    size = self.iface.mapCanvas().size()
    image = QImage(size, QImage.Format_RGB32)

    painter = QPainter(image)
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
    settings = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings()

    layers = settings.layers()
    settings.setLayers(layers)

    job = QgsMapRendererCustomPainterJob(settings, painter)
    job.renderSynchronously()
    painter.end()
```

I see that it's possible to do it with a Map Composer, but I had other problems while saving from Map Composer (mainly with the quality of the image output) : https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html

Is that possible to add a scale bar on my script ?

Comment: If the scale is always the same you could save an image with the scale and then apply it to the final .png of the map. It's a tricky workaround but could work. Surely https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ could do the job.

Comment: Unfortunately, the scale is changing for all of the print. But I define the extent of the image before saving so I can do something similar to draw a scale ! Thank's for the trick. I will try it as soon as possible